# Calculating volume and surface area using java

Tags: java

I am working on a project for my Java I class. I have included the program I’ve written.  My formula seems to be working but my output isn’t. This is the project- “Write a class called Sphere that contains instance data that represents the sphere's diameter.  Define the sphere constructor to accept and initialize the diameter, and include getter and setter methods for the diameter.  Include methods that calculate and return the volume and surface are of the sphere.  Include a toString method that returns a one-line description of the sphere.  Create a driver class called Multisphere, whose main method instantites and updates several Sphere objects.”
Here’s what I have written:

```
public class Sphere 
{

  private double diameter;
  private double calcVol;
  private double calcSA;


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Constructor
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public Sphere(double diameter)
  {
    this.diameter = diameter;
  }
  public void setDiameter(double diameter)
  {
    this.diameter = diameter;
  }
  public double getDiameter(double diameter)
  {
    return diameter;
  }
  public double calcVol()
  {
    return ((Math.PI) * (Math.pow(diameter, 3.0) / 6.0));   
  }
  public double calcSA()
  {
    return ((Math.PI) * Math.pow(diameter, 2.0));   
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Diameter: " + diameter + " Volume: " + calcVol + " Surface Area: " + calcSA;
  }
}

public class MultiSphere 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {


    Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere(6.0);
    Sphere sphere2 = new Sphere(7.0);
    Sphere sphere3 = new Sphere(8.0);d



    sphere1.calcVol();
    sphere2.calcVol();
    sphere3.calcVol();

    sphere1.calcSA();
    sphere2.calcSA();
    sphere3.calcSA();

    System.out.println(sphere1.toString());

    System.out.println(sphere2.toString());

    System.out.println(sphere3.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you shouldn't have `calcVol` and `calcSA` variables. Call the methods instead. And your separate calls to the methods won't work because the return value is not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private double calcVol;
private double calcSA;
```

these are lines you should remove, you declared new fields that have the same names as methods that you also have.

In `toString` you should call your methods like this

```
return "Diameter: " + diameter + " Volume: " + calcVol() + " Surface Area: " + calcSA();
```

also in your `main()` you have an extra `d` in the end of this line

```
Sphere sphere3 = new Sphere(8.0);d
```

Answer (score 1):

*Include methods that calculate and return the volume and surface are of the sphere.*

This is an important line in your homework assignment. There is no mention of any internal state for the volume and the surface area of the sphere, so keeping field values for this doesn't make sense. Your methods are correct, but your `toString` should just call those methods:

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Diameter: " + diameter + " Volume: " + calcVol() + " Surface Area: " + calcSA();

}
```

That way you don't need to call the methods first and your `toString` will always represent the up to date surface area and volume, should the diameter change.